# Is there some compact notation for saying "all the elements of a set"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there some compact notation for saying "all the elements of a set"?

Just trying to save time and be concise really when:

$\forall x\in S:P(x)$ is a bit long-winded to some potential alternative:

$P(\bar S)$

Comment: I feel that $\forall x \in S \, : P(x)$ is the commonly accepted notation. One could use something like $P|_S \equiv \operatorname{true}$, but this looks slightly weird.

Comment: If you're not doing something closely related to logic, it's more common to be even more "long-winded" and to use words, rather than the symbol $\forall$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes people define $P(S)$ to mean $\forall x\in S, P(x)$.  If you explicitly define it this way, then you can use it this way.